# How do I make Vim adapt to the current indenting style of the file I'm editing?

Tags: indentation

I work on a range of JavaScript projects. In most of these projects, the indentation of JavaScript files is 2 spaces, so I've set my default indentation width to that. However it becomes 1 or 4 in some other projects.

Is there a way to ask Vim to change the indentation style based on the style already used in the current file?

Comment: Why dont you add such settings in .vimrc for particular filetype? `:au BufEnter *.js :set shiftwidth=2`. This works for all projects,

Comment: @SibiCoder: Because even the same filetype can have different indenting styles across different projects. (eg: projects not belonging to the same company)

Comment: `*.*` is just a pattern. You can use filename or path as well. Or, you can use similar auto command like what I gave, for each file. You can instruct the auto command to take the tabwidth of current file and put it for path of this file. Its pretty easy.

Comment: Crosslink: same question on  different sites [indentation - How do I make Vim adapt to the current indenting style of the file I'm editing? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/52/) ■ [whitespace - In Vim, how can I automatically determine whether to use spaces or tabs for indentation? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/in-vim-how-c) ■ [editor - Can vim recognize indentation styles (tabs vs. spaces) automatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609233)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Install this plugin: [tpope/vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth)

Comment: Sleuth seems to work a bit better than detectindent, in my experience, and also will try to determine the proper indent settings for new files by looking at other files nearby in the filesystem.

Comment: @jamessan didn't know that, good to know.

Comment: Please read our [policy on plugin-recommendation answers](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/99/24) and add some detail about how exactly to use your recommended plugin to solve the problem.

Answer (score 18):

[ciaranm/detectindent](https://github.com/ciaranm/detectindent) might be what you're looking for. It's unmaintained (last updated in 2015, there was also a fork that was last updated in 2016: [roryokane/detectindent](https://github.com/roryokane/detectindent)) and I haven't used it, but looks like it does what you want:

> A Vim plugin, for automatically detecting indent settings. This plugin adds a :DetectIndent command, which tries to intelligently set the 'shiftwidth', 'expandtab' and 'tabstop' options based upon the existing settings in use in the active file.