# Simple way to store additionnal config in the scope of the actual directory

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, sessions

I have my .vimrc with some global/local configurations, but when I am working in a project, I know that I often create configs (settings, mapping, command, abbreviations, etc.) specifically for this project.

I usually create a session to make them accessible in the directory where I use them with:

```
:mks!
```

That create a `Session.vim` file where my specific configurations are (see `:help mksession`).

I am asking myself if there is a better/simpler way to do so for my use case (if it's possible, a way to load directly my saved settings when I open a file with vim in the same directory).

Comment: *Strongly* related, possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/77/10604

Comment: Oh I see, I haven't noticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head perhaps something like this in your vimrc...

```
let g:localconffile = '.myvimconf'

func! LoadLocalConfig() abort
    let l:fname =  expand('%:p:h') . '/' . g:localconffile
    if filereadable(l:fname)
        exe "source " . l:fname
    endif
endfunc

augroup localconf
  autocmd!
  au VimEnter * call LoadLocalConfig()
augroup END
```

This will look for a file named .myvimconf in the directory of the file being opened and if it's found it will load it (like an additional vimrc file).

`VimEnter` is going to trigger this only when you first open Vim. If you want this to happen for each file opened we'd use something like `BufReadPost`.

This is just the basic idea. You may want to refine and tighten it up. First let's see if it's even the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Nice. It is secure and adjustable.

Comment: B Layer, can I get your input on the possible dupe I linked above?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, that certainly covers the same ground. I have no problem with this being marked dupe.