# Executing settings based on directory during startup

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I am trying to execute some custom settings based on the directory on startup. For this I am trying:

```
autocmd VimEnter /path/to/dir/* :source /custom.vim
```

When I now execute:

```
cd /path/to/dir
vim
```

I would expect the config to have been loaded. This does not seem to work. However, this works:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :source /custom.vim
```

**Is there a way to load a config once on startup based on the directory that vim was started in?**

Note: I am aware of [Applying settings to a directory tree only](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/77/applying-settings-to-a-directory-tree-only) but would prefer to make it work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
augroup DIR_CONFIG | au!
    au VimEnter * if getcwd() == expand('~/temp') | source my.vim | endif
augroup END
```

**PS**, as @eclipse has mentioned in the comments one could just add to vimrc:

```
if getcwd() == expand('~/temp') | source my.vim | endif
```

Comment: Ah, crap...this time you beat me by a lot more than a few seconds. It didn't show up until just now, though. :( Will delete.

Comment: np, we came up to essentially the same answer, indeed.

Comment: Well, great minds think alike, I always say. +1  :)

Comment: Or just `if getcwd() =~# '/some/.*/path' | ...`

Comment: And it probably auto expands `~` according to help

Comment: Btw: could I skip the autocmd all together and just used the if like so:
`if getcwd() == expand('~/temp') | source my.vim | endif`